# GTK 3.0 Compile Error in Dev C++

Tags: gtk, dev-c++

I'm trying to make UI in C for a project. That's when I found  GTK. But after many configurations in dev c++, i simply can't get rid of this error.

```
cannot find -lzdll
```

I tried searching in google but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where libzdll.a  is on your system, and add that path to your compile command using -L.

Comment: My computer tells me that `libz.dll.a` is in C:\gtk\lib but i already included the folder in the libraries in compiler options. Can you tell me how to add the path in compile command?

Comment: If it is really named libz.dll.a, try -lz.dll